# jQuery Owl Carousel animation for items value 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

When I am trying to use owl carousel's animate In and out feature and am showing 2 items, the transition animation is not working.

This is the configuration I am trying: (**items:2**)

```
$('[shoppable-image-container]').owlCarousel({
                loop:true,
                nav: true,
                navText: ["<a><span></span></a>","<a><span></span></a>"],
                lazyLoad : true,
                dots: true,
                animateOut: 'fadeOut',
                animateIn: 'fadeIn',
                items:2,
                margin:10 ,
                autoplay:true,
                // autoplayTimeout:4000,
                smartSpeed:2000  
            });
```

with the following configuration animation it is working fine:(**items:1**)

```
$('[shoppable-image-container]').owlCarousel({
                loop:true,
                nav: true,
                navText: ["<a><span></span></a>","<a><span></span></a>"],
                lazyLoad : true,
                dots: true,
                animateOut: 'fadeOut',
                animateIn: 'fadeIn',
                items:1,
                margin:10 ,
                autoplay:true,
                // autoplayTimeout:4000,
                smartSpeed:2000  
            });
```

How can I achieve multiple items (**specifically 2 items**) animation together using owl Carousel? Is this possible with owl carousel?

Comment: Have you got an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.loop-test').owlCarousel({
     loop: true,
    items: 2,
    nav: true
});
$('.loop-test').on('translate.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $(this).find(".item").hide();
});

$('.loop-test').on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $(this).find(".item").fadeIn(800);
});

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.theme.green.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme loop-test">
   <div class="item"> Your Content </div>
   <div class="item"> Your Content </div>
   <div class="item"> Your Content </div>
   <div class="item"> Your Content </div>
   <div class="item"> Your Content </div>
   <div class="item"> Your Content </div>
   <div class="item"> Your Content </div>
</div>
```